# MongoDB 2.6 $elemMatch operator search values in array whithout $eq operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a request to do to get all the users that have a specified objectId in an array.

I have the following request :

```
var query = {
  'arrayOfIds': { $elemMatch: { $eq: id } },
};
```

This works perfectly in mongodb 3.0.

But in mongodb 2.6 there is no $eq operator. And i have to deploy on mongodb 2.6. So my question is :

How can i do the same things under mongodb 2.6 whithout $eq operator ?

Comment: why cant you query like: var query = {
  'arrayOfIds':  id };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably as complicated as you can do it.

You simply can match the array for the id by

```
db.collection.find({ "yourArray": idToFind})
```

which will return all documents in which's `yourArray` contains `idToFind`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var query = {
  'arrayOfIds._id': id,
};
```

Please try with this!!